# Simple C# camera viewer using raspberry-pi with attached camera module

Tags: c#, winforms, camera, raspberry-pi, webcam

Good day ladies and gentlemen

I'm starting a little project where the C# application views real-time video stream from a camera.

The thing is that the camera that i will be using will be a raspberry pi (any model would do actually) with a camera module attached to it; and everything will be encased in a cheap CCTV camera casing.

My question here is that since the project will revolve around the C# Windows Forms Application, how can I receive the real-time video stream from the raspberry unit (using the C# application)?

Any helpful topics and tips for me to get me started are very much welcomed here.

thanks a bunch

Ian

Comment: Please, consider the folowing link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course, you can use Mono and run C# code right on your Pi!

I haven't done it personally, but you should really look at the tutorials people have posted online. [Here's](http://logicalgenetics.com/raspberry-pi-and-mono-hello-world/) an example.

The thing I find totally cool is that you can develop your camera viewer application on Windows, compile your exe, copy it to your raspberry pi (once you get mono on it), and you can run it.

Hope you get it all working! Raspberry Pi's are fun!

**Edit** take a look at how the camera module interfaces with the pi and what functionality is exposed by the module. Look [Here](http://www.raspberrypi.org/camera). If you go all the way to the bottom, you'll see someone wrote a python implementation for the camera module. Maybe you can read about how they leveraged the module in python and translate that into a c# implementation.

Comment: thanks for the head start. I've just heard of Raspberry Pi a couple of years ago but didn't realized how much potential it has until now. Anyway, I've made some edits to my question (if you haven't read it again).

Comment: I've added some more info to get you started.

Comment: Thanks ryrich. Gonna read this and try integrating it to the project.